# Change user database information not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a function so users are able to change their email in the database. When I submit the form I get an error and the email of the user thats logged in is not changed when I tried to submit the form.

My controller:

```
<?php
class GwController extends CI_Controller {
    // index functie - hierin laad ik de view file 'gegevenswijigen' in het mapje views.
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('gegevenswijzigen');
    }

    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         //Laad het Update_model in models folder
         $this->load->model('Update_model');
    }

    //Controller functie om email van een gebruiker te veranderen
     function update_email() 
     {
         $id= $this->input->post('user_id');
         $data = array(
         'email' => $this->input->post('email'));

         $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];

         //check gebruiker in database
         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('users');
         $this->db->where(array('user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id'], 'wachtwoord' => $wachtwoord));
         $query = $this->db->get();

         $user = $query->row();
         //Als gebruiker bestaat
        if ($user->user_id) {
            $this->Update_model->update_email($id, $data);
            header ('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile');
         }
     }
}
```

My model function:

```
<?php
class Update_model extends CI_Model{


// Model update functie om email te veranderen
function update_email($id,$data){
$this->db->where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->update('users', $data);
$_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
//header ('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile');
}
```

}

My view:

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "GwController/update_email"?>" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td><h4>E-mail adres wijzigen</h4></td>
                    <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'email','id'=>'email', 'name'=>'email', 'placeholder' => 'Nieuw e-mail adres:', 'size'=>70));?></td>
                    <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'password','id'=>'wachtwoord', 'name'=>'wachtwoord', 'placeholder' => 'Uw wachtwoord:', 'size'=>70));?></td>
                    <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'user_id', 'name'=>'user_id', 'value' => $_SESSION['user_id'], 'size'=>70));?></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="emailwijzigen" class="btn btn-primary">Opslaan</button></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
```

This is the error that I'm receiving when I try to fill in the form and submit it:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/GwController.php

Line Number: 45

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/GwController.php
Line: 45
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

This is line 45:

```
if ($user->user_id) {
```

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: could you check if your `$_SESSION['user_id']` has value. or print the query to get the actual sql `$query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();` then echo query to check

Comment: The bigger question here is: why are you checking if a user is logged in in a function of a controller that should only be able to be accessed *when and if* the user is actually logged in. the redundancy in this methodology must be immense. further, hash your passwords! especially if you are passing around the users password like a hot potato... users typically have 1-2 passwords that they use for everything, if you site gets compromised I feel bad for them.

Comment: I did hash the passwords, and yes $_SESSION['user_id'] has value in it

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the troubleshooting steps.

1. Is the $_SESSION['user_id'] set? `echo 'sessid:'.print_r($_SESSION['user_id']);` at the start of the function to check.
2. Does are query yield any results? `echo 'any results?:' . $query->num_rows();` before `$user = $query->row();`
3. If not then let's check manually with `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();` instead of the `$query = $this->db->get();` and try manually with the generated query in phpmyadmin.
4. If phpmyadmin returns no rows and `num_rows()` returns no rows then are condition `$this->db->where(array('user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id'], 'wachtwoord' => $wachtwoord));` is evaluating in such a way that the user with the `user_id` and the password does not exist in the database.
5. Check if the password field is getting anything `echo $_POST['wachtwoord'];`

Also please consider error cases like this. Your code should always take in to account errors. I've taken the liberty of annotating your function so it will properly handle errors.

```
function update_email() {
    $id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $wachtwoord = $this->input->post('wachtwoord');

    // input->post returns null if not set, we need all these variables
    // thus they should all be set
    if (is_null($id) || is_null($email) || is_null($wachtwoord)) {
        exit('Missing parameters'); // handle this nicer with session flash messages
    }

    //check gebruiker in database
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'], 'wachtwoord' => $wachtwoord));
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // there should only be one valid user for the given
    // user_id and password... otherwise we have no results and $user->user_id
    // will fail or we have a bigger problem on our hands (multiple users w/
    // the same id
    if ($query->num_rows() !== 1) {
        exit('User error');
    }

    $user = $query->row();
    //Als gebruiker bestaat
    // not sure what the point of this conditional statement is...
    // could move inside num_rows()
    if ($user->user_id) {
        $this->Update_model->update_email($id, array('email' => $email));
        header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile');
    } else {
        // do something (should always have an else statement in a case like this)
    }
}
```

Further please read this: https://codeinphp.github.io/post/controllers-for-frontend-and-backend-in-codeigniter/

It is a much better way to handle `Admin/LoggedIn` and `Public` sections.

Comment: Sir , I'm getting the error when I submit the form. even thogh I use the right session password

Comment: when i submit the form

Comment: Well obviously something is wrong :) I gave you a comprehensive guide on how to troubleshoot, go through it one by one and it should start to make sense why you are getting this error

Comment: In the comments you said you did hash your password. Where is that code? Like your login model code. Because if you store a hashed pwd in the database then you need to hash it to match it here otherwise it's just plaintext matching with hash and you'll get no results.

Comment: how do you hash your passwords? do you understand what I mean in my previous comment? if I have a password 123123, and its hash is like jrjtht2g54i5o5u25gb4i35g whatever and that hashed value is stored in the db not the plaintext 123123 then if you do a select  with the pwd 123123 it won't come up with any results, you have to hash the password than do the select.

Comment: also you have a security risk, if I change the hidden field user_id to an id of my choosing I can basically modify any users email. don't pass `id` from post to model, in model just get session id `$_SESSION['user_id']`